# Conditional compilation: Getting and testing the package name at compile time

Tags: java, android

There are numerous examples showing how to get the package name in code at runtime.

In my case, I need to test the package name at **compile time**.

Here is my situation: I have two Android projects (the free and the pro) which leverage a library project.
The free version has a "Get the pro version" menu item, which does not exist in the other version.
My menu handling code goes like this:

```
if ( item.getItemId()==R.id.getProVersion ) {
   //...
}
```

Proguard complains that R.id.getProversion does not exist when building the pro package.
So I need to test which project is being built, to exclude this part of the code from being compiled.

Is there a way to know the package name at compile time ?
Are there alterative solutions to this problem ? Either Android-centered or java-centered solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the menu item in the library project, and then use the runtime package name checks to actually decide whether to display the message or not

Comment: Not what I hoped.. But what I did !

Comment: What I do in my code is that I have a base activity in the Library, and then extend it into the free and pro programs, overriding a "shouldDisplayAd" method. But this only works for the main Activity...

Comment: It is indeed a possibility. In my current project however, the src folder is emply for both the pro and free sub-projects. Everything is in the library. But I've also worked on a project where the directories were not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by writing a simple annotation that automatically skips this peace of code. Myabe it's overkill, but it's also a good way to get into preprocessing...

This seems to be a good (KISS) tutorial on the topic:
http://blog.christoffer.me/2011/08/how-to-enforce-static-methods-on-class.html

Comment: Interesting. I'd like an official support for conditional compilation for  java on android. Your solution is a bit overkill for a single variable. I may use it for more complex situations. In the meantime,  I went along the route proposed by miniBill: creating a menu and making it invisible. No the best, but I need to move on.